# Uploading a file to Confluence using powershell

Tags: powershell, curl, confluence

I am trying to add a document to confluence page.

I am using this code :

```
E:\APP\"curl-7.53.1"\src\curl.exe  -v -S -u user:password -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check" -F "file=@C:\Users\srvc_mdw_dev\Desktop\conf.txt" -F "comment=this is my file" "http://example.net/rest/api/content/36375143/child/attachment"
```

But i get the following error :

```
PS E:\PowerShell\script> ./conf
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying IPaddress...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.net (ip address) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> POST /rest/api/content/36375143/child/attachment HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> Authorization: Basic c291aGFpbC5vdWFiaUBtZXRyb2V4dGVybmFsLmZyOm1ldHJvNDU2Kg==
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
> X-Atlassian-Token: no-check
> Content-Length: 333
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------646f724e33da0066
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 302 Found
< Location: https://example.net/rest/api/content/36375143/child/attachment
< Server: BigIP
* HTTP/1.0 connection set to keep alive!
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 0
* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<
* Closing connection 0
```

Do Someone knows why I have this error ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please review the following ***curl*** command the confluence rest api documentation.

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"new page",
"space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":
"storage"}}}' http://localhost:8080/confluence/rest/api/content/ | python -mjson.tool
```

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/